# Angular-Google-Maps ui-gmap-markers not visible

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angular-ui

I am doing a basic load of an array of markers into a google map using angular-google-maps. I am having trouble getting my  directive working properly. I am not getting any errors, but the markers are not showing up. My code is below.

Is there a good way to debug this situation?

HTML:

```
    <ui-gmap-google-map center='map.center' zoom='map.zoom' events='map.events'>
      <ui-gmap-search-box template="searchbox.template" events="searchbox.events" options="searchbox.options" position="searchbox.position"></ui-gmap-search-box>
      <ui-gmap-markers
        models='markers'
        coords='"self"'
        >
      </ui-gmap-markers>
      <ui-gmap-layer type='TransitLayer'></ui-gmap-layer>
    </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

JS:

```
$scope.markers = [{
    id: '5WnUJbhPEg',
    coords: { latitude: 42, longitude: -71 }
}];

$scope.$watch(function() {
        return $scope.markers;
    }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
        console.log('markers changed in $watch');
        console.log($scope.markers);
    }, 
    true
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out that

```
  <ui-gmap-markers
    models='markers'
    coords='"self"'
    >
  </ui-gmap-markers>
```

Should have been

```
  <ui-gmap-markers
    models='markers'
    coords='"coords"'
    >
  </ui-gmap-markers>
```

I think 'self' only works if

```
$scope.markers = [{
    id: '5WnUJbhPEg',
    latitude: 42,
    longitude: -71
}];
```